# update() not being called inside Activity which is Observer

Tags: android, kotlin, observer-pattern

My MainActivity implements the `Observer` class. I also have a class called `ObservedObject` that extends the `Observable` class.

Here is my custom `Observable` , called `ObservedObject`:

```
class ObservedObject(var value: Boolean) : Observable() {
    init {
        value = false
    }

    fun setVal(vals: Boolean) {
        value = vals
        setChanged()
        notifyObservers()
    }

    fun printVal() {
        Log.i("Value" , "" + value)
    }
}
```

Here is my `Application` called `SpeechApp` which contains my `ObservedObject` (an `Observable` actually):

```
class SpeechApp: Application() {
    var isDictionaryRead = ObservedObject(false)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        wordslist = ArrayList()

        Thread {
            execute()
        }.start()
    }

    fun execute() {
        while (/* Condition */) {
            //Log.i("Read" , line)
            /*Does Something Here*/
        }
        isDictionaryRead.setVal(true)
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity`, I mainly have a dialog, that should be displayed after I have got the output after Speech Recognition. It will display as long as the value of `isDictionaryRead` doesn't change to true:

```
class MainActivity(private val REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: Int = 100) : AppCompatActivity() , Observer{
    override fun update(o: Observable?, arg: Any?) {
        (o as ObservedObject).printVal()
        dialog.hide()
    }

    private lateinit var app : SpeechApp
    private lateinit var dialog: MaterialDialog

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Please Wait")
                .content("Loading from the Dictionary")
                .progress(true , 0)
                .build()

        app = application as SpeechApp
        app.isDictionaryRead.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_speech, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        val id = item?.itemId
        when(id) {
            R.id.menu_option_speech -> {
                invokeSpeech()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun invokeSpeech() {
        /* Does Something, Works Fine */

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent , REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT)
        }
        catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            /* Does Something */
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    dialog.show()
                }
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, when the `SpeechApp` sets the value of `isDictionaryRead` to true, I expect it to call the `MainActivity` `update()` method, wherein I have given the code to hide the dialog. That particular code is not working, and my dialog box doesn't go away. Where am I going wrong?

PS. I've pushed my code to [Github](https://github.com/Sparker0i/SpeechCorrection) now, just in case anyone could help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that would cause this problem is that the `execute()` thread that was started in `SpeechApp.onCreate` finished execution and called `isDictionaryRead.setVal(true)` *before* the activity could call `app.isDictionaryRead.addObserver(this)`. As a result, `notifyObservers` is called before the activity even starts observing, and as a result it is not notified. Here's my proposed solution: Start the `execute` thread in the activity's `onCreate` method after adding it as an observer.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    dialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title("Please Wait")
            .content("Loading from the Dictionary")
            .progress(true , 0)
            .build()

    app = application as SpeechApp
    app.isDictionaryRead.addObserver(this)
    app.asyncReadDictionary()
}
```

Then remove the thread call from `SpeechApp.onCreate` and use this instead

```
// in SpeechApp
fun asyncReadDictionary() {
    if (!isDictionaryRead.value) {
       Thread { execute() }.start()
    }
}

private fun execute() {
    while (/* Condition */) {
        //Log.i("Read" , line)
        /*Does Something Here*/
    }
    isDictionaryRead.value = true
}
```

Also, reimplement ObservableObject as follows

```
class ObservedObject : Observable() {
    var value: Boolean = false
        set(newValue) {
            field = newValue
            setChanged()
            notifyObservers()
        }

    fun printVal() {
        Log.i("Value" , "" + value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Still does not work, `update()` in `MainActivity` still not being called

Comment: Wait, it works. Thanks. I've had to make one minor change though in my while logic